# GCC Version inside Docker

Tags: 14.04, gcc

May I know how to know the version of GCC installed inside a docker?

when I tried

```
cat /proc/version
```

It returned with

```
gcc version 4.2.0 20170510 (Ubuntu 4.2.0-6ubuntu1~14.04.12)
```

When I used

```
gcc -v
```

it returned

```
gcc version 7.2
```

I need to use GCC 7.2 inside my docker but I wonder why is it showing GCC 4.2 when I use cat /proc/version

Comment: 14.04? In 2021? That’s quite EOL 

Answer (score 3):

The version in `/proc/version` is the version of the GCC compiler used to build your linux kernal of your host machine

The `gcc -v` is the version of the compiler installed in the docker container